# Kendo upload using Ajax Post to upload files in MVC core

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I have used kendo upload to upload files using Ajax Post in MVC core. I can call the API url but data is coming null. Have i passed data correctly? Here is my code.

```
<form id="uploadForm" action='@Url.Action("UploadFile", new { RmclientAccid = "1"  , AsAtDate = "testdate"})' method="post">
        @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { aria_label = "files" })
                        .Name("fileUpload")
        )
        <p style="padding-top: 1em; text-align: right">
            <button type="submit" class="k-button k-primary">Submit</button>
        </p>
    </form>

$(function () {
            $("#uploadForm").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var upload = $("#fileUpload").data("kendoUpload"),
                    files = upload.getFiles(),
                    myFile = files[0];
                console.log(files);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/RmReportTasks/UploadFile/',
                    dataType: 'json', 
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    data: {
                        fileUpload: files[0].rawFile,
                        RmclientAccid: "1",
                        AsAtDate: "testdate"
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log("succcess")
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        console.log("failure");
                    }
                });
            });
    });
```

Here is my controller.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> UploadFile(IEnumerable<IFormFile> fileUpload , string RmclientAccid, string AsAtDate)
        {
            var result = await _fileUploadManager.UploadDocument(fileUpload, RmclientAccid, AsAtDate);
            return Json(result);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not send files directly using `ajax` to the server.

```
$(function () {
            $("#uploadForm").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var formData = new FormData();
                var totalFiles = document.getElementById("uploadForm").files.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
                   var file = document.getElementById("uploadForm").files[i];
                   formData.append("uploadForm", file);
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/RmReportTasks/UploadFile/',
                    dataType: 'json', 
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    data: formData,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log("succcess")
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        console.log("failure");
                    }
                });
            });
    });
```

And on the server-side, you can receive the file like this.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void UploadFile()
    { 
       for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[i];

                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                // Write logic to handle file here.
            }
   }
```

Comment: If it helped and resolved your issue, you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without form tag element.

Your `CSHTML` Code should be:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
  .Name("uploadFiles")
  .HtmlAttributes(new { aria_label = "files" })           
)
```

Your AJAX Call should be::

```
function OnBrowseSaveClick(e) 
{
  var uploadControl = $("#uploadFiles").data("kendoUpload"); //get a reference of the Upload
  var files = uploadControl.getFiles(); //Get the uploaded files
  var formData = new FormData();
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { //loop through the files
    var file = files[i].rawFile;
    formData.append("uploadFiles", file); //append the property "rawFile" that holds the actual file in the FormData
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: '/Home/SaveFile',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    contentType: false, 
    processData: false, 
    success: function(result) {
      alert('Success');
    },
    error: function(result) {
      swal("Error :" + result.responseText);
    }
  });
}
```

Your Controller Action Should be:

```
public ActionResult SaveFile(IEnumerable<IFormFile> uploadFiles)
{
  // The Name of the Upload component is "uploadFiles" in the partial view.
  if (uploadFiles != null)
  {
    foreach (var file in uploadFiles)
    {
      var fileContent = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition);
        
      // Some browsers send file names with full path.
      // The sample is interested only in the file name.
      var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileContent.FileName.ToString().Trim('"'));
      var physicalPath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "documents", fileName);
    
      using (var fileStream = new FileStream(physicalPath, FileMode.Create))
      {
        file.CopyTo(fileStream);
      }
    }
  }            
  // Return an empty string to signify success.
  return Content("");
}
```